# PHP not displaying database on website

Tags: php, html

I've compiled the following PHP and HTML, what I want to do is connect my WAMP database to my webpage, it's a simple task but the output i receive is displayed in the picture below, can somebody show me where i went wrong?

```
<?php
    //Step 1
    $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'hospital') or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');
?>

<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>
            PHP connect to MySQL
        </h1>
        <?php
            //Step 2
            $query = "SELECT * FROM patients";
            mysqli_query($db, $query) or die('Error querying database.');

            $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                echo $row['id'] . ' ' . $row['patient_name']. ' ' . $row['check_in_date'] . ' ' . $row['room_number'] . ' ' . $row['bed_number'] . ' ' . $row['notes'] . '<br />';
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

[PHP and HTML error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKTu6.png)

Comment: I think you have to close the bracket in the `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){` line

Comment: missing a closing curly bracket in the while loop

Comment: I added the closing curly bracket and it didn't fix it. My output now simply reads " PHP connect to MySQL
'; } ?> "

Comment: add latest code in ur question

Comment: I added the latest code to the question now, it's still not working

Comment: re copy all of your code into the question, looking at your attached image you have a syntax error that isnt in your questions code - the code should work

Comment: @LukeBradley I copied and pasted my code into the question but it was the exact same. It's still giving me the error

Answer (score 1):

I have found some errors in that code

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM patients";
```

You need to add the semicolon a the end of the query code here, so:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM patients;";
```

Then we have this

```
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
   echo $row['id'] . ' ' . $row['patient_name']. ' ' . $row['check_in_date'] . ' ' . $row['room_number'] . ' ' . $row['bed_number'] . ' ' . $row['notes'] . '<br />';
 }
```

This should work

```
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
   $id = $row['id'];
   $patientname = $row['patient_name']; //do this with every variable you have
   echo "$id $patientname";
}
```

EDIT: Also, change this

```
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'hospital') or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');
```

with this

```
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "";
$dbname = "hospital";
$db = mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass) or die ("dbconn");
mysql_select_db($dbname,$db) or die ("msq");
```

Comment: Adding a semicolon at the end of single query is not mandatory

Comment: Hi, I used your code and it doesn't give any errors, however it also does not print the data I want it to

Comment: I added something, try that and let me know

Comment: @Stever I added the code you told me too but unfortunately is still not working

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to assign
`$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);` as you are assigning it inside the while loop

*EDITED ANSWER*

Build a sperate array from the rows and then loop over that, this way you will have more flexibility to add to or edit the results before displaying them

```
//Step 2
$query = "SELECT * FROM patients";
mysqli_query($db, $query) or die('Error querying database.');

$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);

$rows = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $rows[] = $row;
}

foreach($rows as $r) {
    echo $r['id'] . ' ' . $r['patient_name']. ': ' . $r['check_in_date'] . ' ' . $r['room_number'] . ' ' . $r['bed_number'] . ' ' . $r['notes'] . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: I did that but unfortunately the code still seems to not work

Comment: I used the edited answer but unfortunately had the same result

Comment: can u delete all your code @JLally and `echo "working"` using php

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile I did that and nothing now appears on the screen

Comment: Then that means your php code is not being interpreted are u sure the page have a .php extension? And u dont run the file directly from the browser? Are u using a webserver?

Comment: Hi, yes the page is called DevProject2017.php
I'm also running the page in firefox, should I run it elsewhere?

Comment: whats your page url on firefox is it `localhost/DevProject2017.php` or `127.0.0.1/DevProject2017.php`; copy and paste here whats written on your addreess bar when u run the code @JLally

Comment: @JLally in your url bar put `localhost/hospital/DevProject2017.php`

Do you have *another* file in the hospital folder called `DevProject2017.html` ?

Comment: @JLally actually, do you have php installed on your macine?

Comment: Yes, PHP is installed because I'm using it to add data to the database I want to now display, using a different application on my machine

Comment: Also, yes. In my Hospital folder i have two files: DevProject2017.html and DevProject2017.php

Comment: I removed the HTML file frm my folder and now it works. Thank you so much @LukeBradley